# Как в качестве названия именного параметра в функцию передать значение переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некая функция, допустим:
 `def func(name = "1")`
Я хочу в качестве названия именного параметра name передать значение переменной, то есть вместо
 `def func(name = "1")`
вызвать функцию так:

```
name_1 = "2" 
def func(name_1 = "1")
```

Первое что пришло на ум, сделать вот так:

```
name_1 = "2" 
def func(f"{name_1}" = "1")
```

Но увы не сработало - ошибка синтаксиса, может кто подскажет как это сделать и возможно ли вообще?=)

P.S.
Так как многие не понимаю зачем это нужно поясню исходя из исходной задачи:

1. Есть функция

```
 def func1(id_d, name = {name1: id_1}):

      
      def func2 (id_d, name1= 1, name2 = 2)
```

Можно ли вызывать функцию func2 без генерации дополнительного словаря, т.к. в момент вызова func1 мы точно знаем с каким аргументом name мы вызываем функцию func1 и по сути значит знаем с каким аргументом мы должны вызвать функцию func2, ну то есть, если передали бы так:

```
      
      def func2 (id_d, name1= 1, name2 = 2)
```

функция func2 вызвалась бы с аргументом name2
Если сделать так:

```
      key, val = list(name.items())[0]
      params = {key:val}
      def func2 (id_d, **params)
```

Оно отработает, но вопрос был в другом - можно ли как то управлять названием именного параметра при вызове функции?

Comment: Вы не вызов функции, а её описание хотите поменять. Но зачем? Как функция внутри себя будет обращаться с переменной, не зная её имени? Вам и внутри функции придётся как-то "добывать" название параметра функции. Непонятно, зачем это всё нужно. Название параметра может быть произвольным, главное чтобы функция внутри себя использовала то же имя, что и в заголовке функции.

Comment: И да, вы по сути хотите написать `def func("2" = "1")`, если я правильно понимаю ваш пример.  В чём опять же смысл сей записи? )

Comment: Суть такая, у меня есть функция, до ее вызова я определяю с каким параметром буду работать, а потом хочу её вызвать с этим параметром, вот пример кода:
```
 name_id, val_id = list(doc_id.items())[0]
        params = {
            "Документ": generate_record(name_id=val_id, ДопПоля=["ПолныйФормат"],
```
Чтобы не писать для каждого варианта вызова отдельно:
```
        params = {
            "Документ": generate_record(name_id=val_id, ДопПоля=["ПолныйФормат"]
```
Подумал что можно как это параметризировать...

Comment: Вы серьезно? а просто вызвать `def func(name_1)` - что не позволяет?

Comment: Дак не получится, я привел просто пример, но по факту у меня другое:
name_id, val_id = list(doc_id.items())[0] - определяю название аргумента и значение
Вызываю функцию:
generate_record(name_id=val_id)
То есть надо и название аргумента передать и значение

Comment: Ну и + а если перед именным аргументом еще и позиционный будет?Тогда точно название надо передавать же, принципиально это можно как то сделать?

Comment: Ну используйте `**kwargs`, в питоне всё есть. Просто не совсем всё-равно постановка задачи понятна

Comment: Опять же можно в функцию передать словарь, можно передать `json`. Просто непонятно - а что сама функция то ваша делать со всем этим планирует?

Comment: Обычно, когда возникает желание или необходимость сделать что-то подобное, это свидетельствует о неправильной архитектуре вашего кода. Я бы советовал переосмыслить логику работы вашего кода и сделать проще и в питоновском стиле.

Comment: а по моему прикольно было бы если был бы какой нибудь set_name_params, который позволял бы сделать так:
`def func1(id_d, name = {name1: id_1}):
      
      def func2 (id_d, set_name_params(name.keys)[0] = 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть вопроса не очень понятна, но можно передавать в функцию, например, словарь:

```
def func(d):
    for k in d:
        print(k, d[k])

name_1 = 'name1'
val_1 = 'val1'
name_2 = 'бим'
val_2 = 'бом'
func({name_1: val_1, name_2: val_2})
```

Вывод:

```
name1 val1
бим бом
```

Внутри функции вы сможете перебрать все переданные в словаре пары ключ-значение. Можно считать в данном случае ключ в словаре названием переменной, а соответствующее значение - значением этой переменной.

Comment: Я дополнил исходное описание, ну по ходу никак без создания дополнительного словаря никак, я просто думал есть вариант как можно управлять названием именного параметра прямо при вызове функции